# Using separators as functional symbols in first order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Suppose we have the following definition of a term:

> A $term$ is:
>
> - $x$, where "$x$" is a variable
> - $c$, where "$c$" is a constant symbol
> - $f(\tau_1,...,\tau_n)$, where "$f$" is a functional symbol with $n$ arguments and $\tau_1,...,\tau_n$ are also terms
> - $(\tau)$, where $\tau$ is also a term
>
> You can also use the symbols comma "$,$" left bracket "$($" and right bracket "$)$" as constant or functional symbols.

Prove or disprove that if two terms are symbolically equivalent, then their interpretations are also equivalent regardless what the variable assignment is.

Here are some examples:

$\tau=f((,))$ - this can be interpreted in two ways: $f(c,d)$ where $'(' = c$ and $')'=d$ or $f((c))$ where $',' = c$. This doesn't cause ambiguity since we know how arguments $f$ has.

$\tau=(((x))$ - this also can be interpreted in two ways: $(f(x))$ where $'(' = f$ or $f((x))$ where $'(' = f$. These two terms are structurally different but essentially they refer to the same object after variable assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `f((,),(,))` where `f` is a three-argument function and `(`, `)`, and `,` are also constants.

Comment: Perfect answer!... Thanks!